# NumPy - Remove subarrays containing identical elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have the following 4 by 3 by 3 array,

```
array([[[-2, -2, -2],
        [-2, -2, -2],
        [-2, -2, -2]],

       [[-2, -2, -2],
        [-2, -2, -2],
        [-2, -2, -2]],

       [[-2, -2, 71],
        [-1, -1, -1],
        [71, -1, 52]],

       [[-2, -2, -2],
        [-2, -2, -2],
        [-2, -2, -2]]])
```

I would like to filter such array by the following standard:

Treat each 3 by 3 array as a block. If all elements in this block are equal to -2, we should cut the whole block, so the target array would look like this (1 by 3 by 3):

```
array([[[-2, -2, 71],
        [-1, -1, -1],
        [71, -1, 52]]])
```

I could only come up with a brute force solution with an explicit `if` condition and a `for` loop, but it does not work. Can anyone share a better method?

You can recreate the original array by the following commands

```py
array = np.array([[-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2],
    [-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2],
    [-2,-2,71,-1,-1,-1,71,-1,52],
    [-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2]])
newarr = array.reshape(4,3,3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers are nice if you expect your arrays along axis 0 to always be a specific value, like -2, or 872385, etc.

In case you want something more general where you want to filter out any arrays which contain a single value, you can filter arrays by rank.

Since any matrix of a single value will have rank 1, you can filter by `rank != 1`:

```py
In [2]: x[np.linalg.matrix_rank(x) != 1]
Out[2]:
array([[[-2, -2, 71],
        [-1, -1, -1],
        [71, -1, 52]]])
```

This will work for any matrix along axis 0 which is filled with the same values. Another example:

```py
In [4]: x
Out[4]:
array([[[ 5,  5,  5],
        [ 5,  5,  5],
        [ 5,  5,  5]],

       [[-2, -2, -2],
        [-2, -2, -2],
        [-2, -2, -2]],

       [[-2, -2, 71],
        [-1, -1, -1],
        [71, -1, 52]],

       [[99, 99, 99],
        [99, 99, 99],
        [99, 99, 99]]])

In [5]: x[np.linalg.matrix_rank(x) != 1]
Out[5]:
array([[[-2, -2, 71],
        [-1, -1, -1],
        [71, -1, 52]]])
```

Comment: This solution will filter singular matrices as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, it uses the filter array feature and the `all()` function in NumPy :

```py
filterarr = []
for arr in newarr:
    if np.all(arr==-2):
        filterarr.append(False)
    else:
        filterarr.append(True)

newarr = newarr[filterarr]
print(newarr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.where`:

```py
data[np.where(np.any(data != -2, axis=-1))]
```

With the given array as `data`, the output is:

```py
[[-2 -2 71]
 [-1 -1 -1]
 [71 -1 52]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just select for the negation of where all the array along the 2nd and 3rd axes are equal to `-2`:

```
>>> arr
array([[[-2, -2, -2],
        [-2, -2, -2],
        [-2, -2, -2]],

       [[-2, -2, -2],
        [-2, -2, -2],
        [-2, -2, -2]],

       [[-2, -2, 71],
        [-1, -1, -1],
        [71, -1, 52]],

       [[-2, -2, -2],
        [-2, -2, -2],
        [-2, -2, -2]]])
>>> ~(arr == -2).all(axis=(1,2))
array([False, False,  True, False])
```

And use boolean indexing on the first axis:

```
>>> arr[~(arr == -2).all(axis=(1,2)), ...]
array([[[-2, -2, 71],
        [-1, -1, -1],
        [71, -1, 52]]])
```